# annotation on pgfplot table

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplotstable

In this example table, how can I draw a line from (1,2) to (4,2)?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
    C1     C2
    6       80
    15      520
    25      650
    35     1100
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable, booktabs, colortbl}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\pgfplotstableset{
    every head row/.style={before row={\toprule},after row={\midrule}},
    every last row/.style={after row={\bottomrule}},
    every even row/.style={before row={\rowcolor[gray]{0.9}}},
    columns/.style={dec sep align,%column type=c
    }
}
\begin{document}
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[]{data.dat}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A priori `pgfplotstable` does not put its cells in nodes. So we have to do that on our own. This can be done using `assign cell content/.code` and the `tikzmark` library. Please note the **e** before `value` in `\pgfkgyssetevalue` (and the `\noexpand`) which was required to "trick" `pgfplotstable` to share the row and column indices with us to create unique node names.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{data.dat}
    C1     C2
    6       80
    15      520
    25      650
    35     1100
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable, booktabs, colortbl}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\pgfplotstableset{
    every head row/.style={before row={\toprule},after row={\midrule}},
    every last row/.style={after row={\bottomrule}},
    every even row/.style={before row={\rowcolor[gray]{0.9}}},
    columns/.style={dec sep align,%column type=c
    },assign cell content/.code={%
    \pgfkeyssetevalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{%
    \noexpand\tikzmarknode{mytab-\the\numexpr\pgfplotstablerow+1\relax-\the\numexpr\pgfplotstablecol+1\relax}{#1}}}
}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[]{data.dat}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
 \draw[blue] (mytab-1-2) to[bend right=50] (mytab-4-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, is it possible to include the table the the tikzpicture?

Comment: @lucky1928 Unfortunately I do not think that this would be safe as this nests `tikzpicture`s. If you put it in a savebox, you can use it inside a `tikzpicture`.